# Unity 4.6 compatability with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk, unity-game-engine

The current Unity Facebook SDK(7.3) says its only compatible with Unity 5 since September 2015. I'm trying to update an Android game built in Unity 4.6 and I noticed the live version of the game's Facebook features currently don't run, and my Unity project builds can't login to Facebook either.

Are the previous versions of the Facebook SDK, like version 6, prior to September 2015 work or is the only way to get Facebook functioning in Unity today by upgrading to Unity 5?

I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this on the Facebook or Unity developer forums that is recent.  Does anyone have a Unity 4.6 game currently working with Facebook?

The error I get in Android is an "error validating access token" but before I start investigating further I figured I'd see if this is only the beginning of a bigger and more obvious problem.

Comment: IMO you'll never, really, get a specific answer to that  :/  Realistically you have to go to Unity5; it's the only way.  Facebook is a living hell and your fellow engineers share your pain  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I looked into it further and I got the basic features to work for Unity 4.6 Android if you're using version 6 of the Facebook Unity SDK.  So I suppose that answers it.

Thanks for the feedback, guys.

Answer (score 1):

All releases of Facebook Unity sdk are listed on [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads)